# Service Fabric Remoting Exception -> upgrade from v1 to v2

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

We have an application that has been running on Service Fabric for a while using remoting with stateless services. After upgrading to Remoting v2, some methods are failing with the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Type 'System.String[]' cannot be added to list of known types since
 another type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]' with the same data contract name 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:ArrayOfstring' is already present. If there
 are different collections of a particular type - for example, List<Test> and Test[], they cannot both be 
added as known types.  Consider specifying only one of these types for addition to the known types list.'

at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ServicePartitionClient`1.<InvokeWithRetryAsync>d__23`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.Client.ServiceRemotingPartitionClient.<InvokeAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ProxyBase.<InvokeAsyncV2>d__21.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running into an [existing](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric-issues/issues/502) [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric-issues/issues/497) with remoting v2. V2 requires  Remoting Api Types be of concrete Type.

- don't use `IEnumerable<string>` but `string[]` in contracts.
- or provide a [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#how-to-use-custom-serialization-with-remoting-v2) implementation of `IServiceRemotingMessageSerializationProvider`